# Crystal Report is not showing data after some time

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

i already went through the following questions.please don't mark as duplicate to my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432683/crystal-report-is-not-showing-data-after-some-time-in-cr-version-13-0-2000-0
I am facing this issue since last 1 month.My crystal report are working fine development environment (windows-7 32bit,VS2010,Crystal report V.13). I deployed on server (windows server-2012 64bit,core i5 ). Problem is that after some time report getting blank.I search a lot about that and use Dispose(),Close() method,right now I m using the following code.

```
public static void OpenPdfInBrowser(ReportClass RptReport)
{
        string strFilename;
        string strFolderName;
        string strFile = String.Empty;
        string strReportOutputName = String.Empty;

        HttpResponse objResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        HttpSessionState objSession = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        HttpServerUtility objServer = HttpContext.Current.Server;

        strFolderName = objServer.MapPath("../ReportOutput");
        if (Directory.Exists(strFolderName) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strFolderName);
        }

        //Generate the File Name
        strFilename = "";
        strFile = objSession.SessionID.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".pdf";
        strFilename = strFolderName + "\\" + strFile;

        //Set the File Name
        DiskFileDestinationOptions diskOpts = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
        diskOpts.DiskFileName = strFilename;

        //Set the Various Options
        ExportOptions exportOpts = new ExportOptions();
        exportOpts = RptReport.ExportOptions;
        exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
        exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        exportOpts.DestinationOptions = diskOpts;
        //Export the Report
        RptReport.Export();
        //Stream it to the Client
        objResponse.ClearContent();
        objResponse.ClearHeaders();
        strReportOutputName = "Report";
        objResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        objResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Report.pdf");
        objResponse.WriteFile(strFilename);
        objResponse.Flush();
        objResponse.Close();
        //Delete the File   
        System.IO.File.Delete(strFilename);
        //Close the Report Object
        RptReport.Close();
        RptReport.Dispose();
        GC.Collect();
    }

   I am getting the following error in event viewer on deployment server.
   The description for Event ID 4353 from source Crystal Reports cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
    If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
    The following information was included with the event:
```

The keycode assembly, BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder.dll, cannot be loaded.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks in adnvace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research my problem has been resolved by doing following changes in registry.Actually this issue is related to Print Job Limit which by default 75 I just extend its data size according to my requirement and it work for me.

Go to-->RUN----->Regedit
1-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
2-SOFTWARE
3-SAP BUSINESS OBJECT
4-CRYSTAL REPORT FOR .NET FRAMEWORK(your version no.)
5-REPORT APPLICATION SERVER 
6-SERVER

then got to "PrintJobLimit" PROPERTY and change its Data size to whatever you want.
thanks for every one who help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Copy your asp.net folder to server virtual directory...

Not sure but hope ur problem will resolve. Best Luck.

Comment: Hi  @Tukaram ,I already did this but its not work for me.thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The issues is looking like, related to the Crystal report installation on the server... If its working fine on the Development Machine and if All the applications required to run the crystal reports are installed on the Deployment server, then please, check.. Application Pool in IIS --> select the Application Pool used for the Web applicaiton --> Advanced Settings-> Enable 32-Applications --> Set this to "True" ..

Please, try and check...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct to use .close and . dispose but the best way to use it is :

```
 Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    cryRpt.Close()
    cryRpt.Dispose()
End Sub
```

to open crystal report in PDF you can use http response it will be better in performance :

```
    cryRpt = New ReportDocument
    cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("Your report path"))
    cryRpt.SetDataSource(Your data source)
   cryRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "ExportedReport")
```

Comment: Rahman: thanks for your reply  i already tried by using PageUnload but it's not working and one more thing  when i use cryRpt.ExportHttpResponse(). I get the error "unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or native frame is on top of call stack"